# Adding a prefix to PIVOT columns

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm `PIVOT`ing a table such that the column names in the final table are based on the "organization name" in the source table.  The problem is, the "organization name" is data-driven and could be any set of values; I use dynamic SQL to build up the `PIVOT`'s `IN` clause.  This means that the value could match another column name I have, like the `RecordId` I'm pivoting against.  So I have something like this:

```
.----------------------------------------------------------------------.
| RecordId | OrganizationFoo | OrganizationBar | OrganizationBaz | ... |
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----|
| 123      | 182             | 76              | 56              | ... |
| 234      | 846             | 0               | 182             | ... |
| 345      | 46              | 2               | 951             | ... |
...
```

The problem is, this is all data-driven so it would be fine for an organization name to be `RecordId`, which would cause an invalid SQL query to be generated because of duplicate columns.  Is there a way I can automatically prefix something to every column in the `PIVOT` output?

If not, the only 3 ways I can think of doing it are:

- Select `CONCAT('Prefix_', [OrgName])` instead, but this will probably reduce efficiency because `[OrgName]` is indexed.
- Create a duplicate table to the one holding `[OrgName]`, and each time this query is run, clear it and insert the contents of the original table but with `[OrgName]` having the prefix instead.
- Just always store `[OrgName]` with the prefix in the first place.

Any cleaner/better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index use seems irrelevant to the concatenation.
The other 2 solutions are awkward.

Demo

```
create table t (x int,code varchar(100))

insert into t values 
    (1,'X'),(1,'X'),(1,'Y'),(1,'Y'),(1,'Y'),(1,'Z'),(2,'X'),(2,'X'),(2,'Y')
```

---

```
select  *
from    t pivot (count(code) for code in([x],[y],[z])) p
```

> Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The column name "x" specified in
>   the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the
>   PIVOT argument.
>   Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The column 'x'
>   was specified multiple times for 'p'.

```
select  *
from    (select x,'my_prefix_' + code as code from t) t 
            pivot (count(code) for code in([my_prefix_x],[my_prefix_y],[my_prefix_z])) p
```

---

```
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| x | my_prefix_x | my_prefix_y | my_prefix_z |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | 2           | 3           | 1           |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2 | 2           | 1           | 0           |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Yep, you're right about the performance being the same.  Strange, I thought I'd tested the non-concatenated version as being faster.  Oh well, I guess concatenation is the cleanest solution.  Thanks.

Comment: P.s. there is also the option to give aliases to the fixed columns